# Add 2 bar columns and 1 line column in 1 plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a `df_daily` where I want to have 2 columns `daily_sentiment_polarity`and `daily_sentiment_subjectivity` as bars on a plot and 1 column `close` as a line in the plot. The x axis should be the variable `date`.

I have tried the following:

```
df_daily.plot(kind='bar', x='date', y='daily_sentiment_polarity')
df_daily.plot(kind='bar', x='date', y='daily_sentiment_subjectivity')
df_daily.plot(kind='line', x='date', y='close')
```

But this resulted in 3 seperate plots. Can someone help me merge these 3 into 1 plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data={"date":["01-05-2021","02-05-2021","03-05-2021"],
    'daily_sentiment_polarity':[0,1,0],
    'daily_sentiment_subjectivity':[1,1,0],
    'close':[10,20,5]
}

df_daily=pd.DataFrame(data)
ax=df_daily.plot(kind='bar', x='date', y=['daily_sentiment_polarity','daily_sentiment_subjectivity'])
df_daily.plot(kind='line', x='date', y='close',ax=ax, color='r',secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! The code works, the only weird thing is that I actually don't see the close line in my own plot